# Delete all of a table's records and replace them with another table's records using VBA

Tags: sql, vba, dao

I'm not quite sure why this isn't working. Debug is giving me an error: 
`Item not found for rs2.Fields(fld) = rs1.Fields(fld)`

Here's my code:

```
CurrentDb.Execute "DELETE * FROM " & appendTo_text.Value & ";", dbFailOnError
Set db = CurrentDb()
Dim fld As DAO.Field
Set rs1 = db.OpenRecordset(tableName_text.Value)
Set rs2 = db.OpenRecordset(appendTo_text.Value)
For Each fld In rs1.Fields
  rs2.AddNew
  rs2.Fields(fld) = rs1.Fields(fld)
  rs2.Update
Next

Set fld = Nothing
rs1.Close
rs2.Close
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where's the part where you loop through all the rows? Plus, you're adding a new row for each field, rather than for each row. Finally, the problem is that `fld` inside the loop is an object, which when treated as a string will implicitly convert, returning the default property of `Value`. So you're trying to select the field via the field **value** from the other recordset--you should be using the field **name** from the other recordset.

```vb
Do While Not SourceRecordset.Eof
   TargetRecordset.AddNew
   For Each Field In SourceRecordset.Fields
      TargetRecordset.Fields(Field.Name).Value = Field.Value
   Next
   TargetRecordset.Update
Loop
```

Also, could you please not name the variables `rs1` and `rs2`? At least name them `SourceRecordset` and `TargetRecordset`. You don't want the developer coming after you to lie awake at night fantasizing about hunting you down and doing bad things to you.

If you are doing a lot of rows, you may also want to look into `UpdateBatch` and how to disconnect the recordset, so that you have decent performance.

Finally, if you do still have performance problems, recognize that the syntax `Recordset.Fields(Field.Name).Value` is *slow*. (If you were using ADODB, the fastest method would be to pass in an array of values directly in the `AddNew` method). However, you can still get a speed boost by obtaining a reference to each field like so:

```vb
Dim SourceOrderID As DAO.Field
Set SourceOrderID = SourceRecordset.Fields("OrderID")
Dim TargetOrderID As DAO.Field
Set TargetOrderID = TargetRecordset.Fields("OrderID")
```

Then instead of using `For Each` inside the `Do While` loop, just assign:

```vb
TargetOrderID.Value = SourceOrderID.Value
TargetOrderDate.Value = SourceOrderDate.Value
```

I guarantee this will be faster.

Also, if you are looking for speed improvements, if you've used `With` like in examples found in online in Microsoft documentation for DAO, try it without `With` to see if it's faster.

Comment: Thanks this helped a lot. I didn't even know of the .eof function; I'm very new to VBA and programming in general (I'm sure you could tell.)

So sticking with the first method, because the goal here is to stick wit DOA instead of ADO, I am getting a data type conversion error. Is this because there are points where fields are being passed as null or are they being passed as empty fields (if they are empty)?

Also, is it even necessary to declare 'Field' at the top or is it automatically set when constructing the loop?

Comment: I would assume that the fields don't match data types, just as the error suggests. Set your VBA project to break on error, then when it blows up, examine the values in the fields to see what is going on. (Press Alt+F11 to get to the visual basic editor if you're not already there, then press Ctrl+G to get to the immediate pane, and you can do `? Field.Value` or `? Field.Type` (where `?` is short for `Debug.Print`). See http://bytecomb.com/microsoft-access-field-data-type-reference/

Comment: Thanks again for your help. These are obviously very helpful, essential tools for troubleshooting.

Comment: I updated a bit. Note that getting a reference to a field is also a DAO thing.